# JMS migration from JBoss 5.1 GA to EAP 6.4

Tags: jboss, jms, java-ee-7, jboss-eap-6

I have this code on my JBoss 5.1 web application compatible:

```
public class SendNotification {

    @Resource(mappedName="queue/QueueNotification")
    private Queue destination;
    @Resource(mappedName="ConnectionFactory")
    private QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public void sendMessageToDestination(Mymessage message) {
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        sessione = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageProducer producer = sessione.createProducer(destination);
        ObjectMessage message = sessione.createObjectMessage();
        message.setObject(messaggio);
        ..
        producer.send(...
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm trying to migrate to JBoss EAP 6, but on deploy I receive this error:

**SendNotification \".destination is missing**

Then I tried to configure *standalone-full.xml* with:

```
<jms-destinations>                  
    <jms-queue name="MyAppQueueNotification">
        <entry name="java:/jms/queue/MyAppQueueNotification"/>                        
    </jms-queue>                    
    ...
```

But nothing changed... What's wrong with it ?

Comment: Have you tried the [Red Hat Application Migration Toolkit](https://developers.redhat.com/products/rhamt/download/)? It could give you a hint on what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the link helps: [Migration](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Migration_Guide/chap-Migrate_Your_Application.html) 
Section 3.1.8.4.

Please try to change `@Resource(mappedName="queue/QueueNotification")` to  `@Resource(mappedName="java:/queue/QueueNotification")`

Comment: try creating queue with jndi "java:jboss/exported/queue/QueueNotification" and use jndi "/queue/QueueNotification" while doing lookup